# Recursion Davis' Staircase understanding

Tags: recursion

I'm going through a hackerrank challenge on recursion https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-recursive-staircase

and I'm having difficulty understanding how the solution below solves the problem. Here's the tree (the recursion calls) like you would with the fibonacci problem but I don't see the insight

With N = 3 the possible choices are

- 3
- 1,1,1
- 2,1
- 1,2

But I don't see these states represented in the tree, I guess I'm not following the logic which makes it hard for me to solve recursive problems

```
func f(int n){
   if (n < 0) /* base case */
    return 0;
   if (n == 0) /* base case */
    return 1;

   return f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think you mean when you say, “With N = 3 the possible **choices** are”?

Comment: Also, could you please share with us where you got the "solution below" (the four bulletined values), and why you think that it is correct.

Comment: You never state the problem. The hackerrank link might rot one day, so you should state the problem (in your own words) while giving credit and linking to hackerrank.

Answer (score 5):

Your base case seems to be wrong.
Suppose we want to climb $n$ stairs, we want to compute $F(n)$. There are three possibilities which can be defined recursively:
1) First cover 1 stair, then there are $F(n-1)$ ways to continue. 
2) First cover 2 stairs, then there are $F(n-2)$ ways to continue. 
3) First cover 3 stairs, then there are $F(n-3)$ ways to continue.

So we need to add these three options
$$F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-3)$$
where base case is

$$F(1) = 1, F(2)=2, F(3) = 4$$

**UPDATE** (on Charles, and quicksort comments):

**How to derive base cases**

$F(1)$ means we have only one stair and thus there is only one way to climb it. So, $F(1)=1$.

For $F(2)$ we have two stairs and there are only two ways to climb it: First stair, and then the second, or directly jump on the second stair. So, $F(2) = 2$.

Similarly for $F(3)$. We may move to the first stair, then to the second, and then to the third one. We may also jump to the second and then to the third, or alternatively step on the first and then jump to the third. And finally we could directly jump to the third stair. In total, four possibilities, $F(3) = 4$.

The following is the pseudocode:

```
 Count(N)
   if N == 1 return 1
   if N == 2 return 2
   if N == 3 return 4
   return Count(N-1) + Count(N-2) + Count(N-3)
 end
```

As for the above tree, you don't need to "unravel" for the case $N=3$ since it is the base case which is handled in a single if-statement. However, for $N=5$ the recursion tree would look like as the following:

```
                      ( 5 )
                     /  |  \
                    /   |   \ 
                   /    |    \
                  /     |     \
                (4)    (3)    (2)
               / | \    |      |
              /  |  \   4      2 
            (3) (2) (1)
             |   |   |
             4   2   1
```

Note that the above method of counting is **the most terrible way since you always solve the same subproblems** (overlapping subproblems) many times which leads to the exponential time. You could rewrite the algorithm which solves iteratively without using recursion as following

```
Count(n)
  if n == 1 return 1
  if n == 2 return 2
  if n == 3 return 4

  x1 = 1
  x2 = 2
  x3 = 4
  i = 4

  while i <= n
    sum = x1 + x2 + x3
    x1 = x2
    x2 = x3
    x3 = sum
    i+=1
  end

  return sum
end
```

Finally (as quicksort noted in his/her comment), you could [solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) the above recurrence relation and find the closed form formula which gives you $O(1)$ solution (without need to compute the entire sequence up to $N$).

Comment: I think it would be (much) more helpful to the OP if you could show how you actually derived those base case values. Which is to say, to show how you "unravelled" the recursive calls and summed the values within the return statements.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a closed formula, it can be obtained by standard methods.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for comments. I'll update accordingly. Cc:@quicksort

Comment: @fade2black I was hoping that you would have derived the base case values by actually using the presented code, and not through a more, conversational and exhaustive, method. Perhaps I'll post an answer in the morning.

Comment: @Charles, I am very curious how you could derive for example $F(1)$ through the code or relation. They are BASE CASES.

Comment: @fade2black The OP explicitly provides the function f(). You can derive the base case values from the fact that this is a third order linear homogeneous recurrence relation, and by looking at the code. And the reason why I suggest this method instead of something more conversational is because its much more consistent, procedural, less cumbersome, and applicable to most all problems like this, when provided with information similar to what the OP has offered.

Comment: @fade2black I'm not saying that your assessment or description of what the base case values are, or what they represent, is incorrect, but that I just don't think it's (directly) helpful to the OP to provide it in such a way, since the OP is expressing confusion in  understanding the recursive calls and how to trace the code with respect to the return values.

Comment: @Charles, first of all $f$ is not provided by the problem statement. You should come up with it yourself as asker did (but wrongly), so you may not look at the code, just start with the problem statement. Second, suppose you have a linear hom. recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$. How would you solve it without initial values/boundary values/base cases? Any idea? No $f$ and no source code, just linear equations.

Comment: @fade2black My mistake.. I was thrown off by the format in which the OP expressed the base cases. From "func f(n)" the base case values can be derived (of course).

Comment: @Charles Anyway, I am glad to see your post. You are welcome to post your own solution. :-), no harm I think.

Comment: Could someone please explain why F(n)=F(n−1)+F(n−2)+F(n−3)? I just don't get it.